# controller blog and function is Login

Tags: php, codeigniter, session, authentication

session not destroying from this one and  this is my controller file blog.php

```
    parent::__construct();
    $this->load->helper(array('form', 'url'));
    $this->load->library('session');
    $this->load->library('form_validation');
    $this->load->model('register/blogmodel');
}
function login(){
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('username', 'Username', 'required|min_length[5]|max_length[25]');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('password', 'Password', 'required');
    if ($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE){
    $this->load->view('Login/login');
                }
    else{   
    $result = $this->blogmodel->validate();
    if(! $result){
        // If user did not validate, then show them login page again
    $data['msg'] = "Invalid username and/or password.";
    $this->load->view('Login/login',$data);
                 }
                  else{
                  redirect('blog/home', 'refresh');
                       }        
                        }
```

this is my logout function

```
 function logout(){

    $user_data = $this->session->all_userdata();
    foreach ($user_data as $key => $value) {
        if ($key != 'session_id' && $key != 'ip_address' && $key != 'user_agent' && $key     != 'last_activity') {
            $this->session->unset_userdata($key);
        }
    }
    $this->session->sess_destroy();
    redirect('/blog/index');
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Please check your login() and logout() function are in the same controller or not if it is is same controller then below two line code is right for logout and clear all session data

```
$this->session->sess_destroy();
redirect('/blog/index');
```

If  your login() and logout() function are in the not in the same controller then you need to start one line in logout function

```
$this->load->library('session');
$this->session->sess_destroy();
redirect('/blog/index');
```

I think it may be work if other is not affected

Comment: with this session not destroying and whenever i click on any link new session id created without user data on every link a new session created